# Starting rails dev server results in cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory puma_http11.so (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I'm trying to start rails server (puma) using command `rails s`

I get this error:

> rails s I, [2017-11-16T10:47:05.872867 #16905]  INFO -- sentry: **
>   [Raven] Raven 2.5.1 configured not to capture errors: Not configured
>   to send/capture in environment 'development'
>   => Booting Puma
>   => Rails 5.1.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options Exiting /home/mariusz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory -
>   /home/mariusz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.so
>   (LoadError)   from
>   /home/mariusz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in`block in require'

My project info:
puma (3.10.0), rails (5.1.3), ruby 2.4.0

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with invalid environment. I needed to restore all my gems to pristine state. Running `gem pristine --all` helped. (it takes about 10 min to finish it)

Comment: This forces recompilation of gem native extensions. When you've changed the underlying dynamically linked libraries a rebuild is required. `gem pristine` solves that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way.
Go to the  `tmp/pids`  folder then in the  `server.pids`  file  erases the content of this file. The content is the pid of the server rails execution process.